# Problems validating App with embedded frameworks in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xamarin, app-store

I embedded a thirdy party framework in my Xamarin project following the walkthrough:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough

Steps:

1. I created in XCode a Swift project including the thirdy party framework called AcmeFramework.
2. I compiled the XCode project obtaining a new framework called AcmeProxy.
3. In Visual Studio I created a iOS Binding Library including the frameworks as Native frameworks:

- AcmeFramework
- AcmeProxy

4. In my App Visul Studio project, I added the Binding Library as a reference.
5. I've used correctly the library in the code
6. All compiles correctly and runs correctly on iPhone
7. I created the Archive for iOS and is Ok
8. When I try to distrubute the package it brokes in the validation step:

> Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file 'App.iOS.app/Frameworks/AcmeProxy.framework/Modules/AcmeProxy' is not permitted. Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries, other than a valid CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure.

I reviewed the steps many times.
What's wrong with the process?

Comment: Hi, from shared error logs: `Your app can’t contain standalone executables or libraries`, it indicates the included third party framework can not work. You'd better not use the third party library to create bining library. It can not make sure that there is no conflict when compiling.

Comment: Well, I need the third party library to execute special functions. The binding library is useful just to include the library. The project compiles and executes correctly. The problem is when I try to upload the package to the Apple Store.

Comment: I fear the iOS Application bundle cannot include custom framework, as stated in the official Apple Bundle Structure Guide: https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure

Comment: Hi, it seems that Apple will not limit that, if so we can not reference some SDK projects inside our proejcts. It should be other reasons result of this.